# Remove javascript code from bundle during production build

Tags: javascript, gulp, bundle, browserify, uglifyjs

I noticed that ReactJS has some debug messages that appears only in development mode.

When I set `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';` in my gulpfile.js before bundling, the debug messages disappears.

How can I write such code, that appears only in development (debug) build but are not bundled into production build?

something like:

```
function sayHello(message){
  #IF DEBUG
     if (!message) console.log("message cannot be null");
  #ENDIF

  alert(message);
}
```

---

EDIT:
 when I tried to use `if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')` then gulp-uglify correctly removed the code from bundle in production build. 
However, at runtime (in browser), `process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined and the condition on never met.

How it is possible, that it works in react?

```
var browserify = require("browserify");
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

var bundler = browserify({ debug: false })
   .require('react')
   .require('react-dom')

bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source("reactbundle.js"))
    .pipe(buffer());
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDir + 'scripts'));
```

Comment: https://github.com/hughsk/envify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a typescript version but have you tried [gulp-remove-code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remove-code)? You can surround your JavaScript with some comments to remove whatever code you want when running your production build. This is from the above linked page:

```
var removeCode = require('gulp-remove-code');

gulp.src('./src/file.js')
  .pipe(removeCode({ production: true }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))


//removeIf(production) 
value = JSON.stringify({key: 'value'}, null, 2);
//endRemoveIf(production)
```

Comment: Should be accepted as the correct answer. StackOverflow is riddled with many other threads covering this sort of question though.